# Unknown operation in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have three vectors called:

$$a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N)_{1\times N}$$

$$b=(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_N)_{1\times N}$$

$$c=(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_N)_{1\times N}$$

If I create a fourth one named:

$$d = \operatorname{diag}(a^T b) = (a_1b_1,a_2b_2,\ldots,a_Nb_N)$$

Is it possible for me to affirm the following?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}{a_i b_i c_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}{d_i c_i} = d \cdot c$$

---

**Update:** Doing some coding in python it looks fine:

```
import numpy as np

N = 5
a  = np.expand_dims(range(N),1)
b  = np.expand_dims(range(N),1)
c  = np.expand_dims(range(N),1)
d = np.diagonal(a.T*b)

cd = np.dot(d,c)
print "cd =", cd

sum = 0
for iter in range(N):
    sum += a[iter] * b[iter] * c[iter]
print "sum = ", sum
```

Output:

```
cd = [100]
sum =  [100]
```

Comment: Is there another way to get the $(a_1b_1, a_2b_2, ..., a_Nb_N)$ vector?

Answer (score 2):

> $d = \mbox{diagonal}(a^T b) = (a_1b_1,a_2b_2,...,a_Nb_N)$

Yes, that gives 
$$
\mbox{diag}(a^T\, b) = \mbox{diag}(a_i b_j) = \sum a_i b_i = a \cdot b = a \, b^T 
$$

But $a\, b^T$ is simpler.

> $$
> \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{N}{a_i b_i c_i}}_\mbox{scalar} 
> = \sum_{i=1}^{N}{d_i c_i} = \underbrace{{c \cdot d}}_\mbox{vector} \quad (*)
> $$

Going from the right:
$$
c \, d = c (a \cdot b) 
= (c_i) \left(\sum_j a_j b_j\right) 
= \left(c_i \sum_j a_j b_j\right)
= \left(\sum_j c_i a_j b_j\right)
$$
as $d$ is a scalar. The rightmost term is a vector with those sums as $i$-th component of the vector. And it features $c_i$ not $c_j$.

So the above equation $(*)$ will not hold in general.

Comment: Doesn't he want a scalar?

Comment: Thanks Mvw, but $c \cdot d$ is a scalar, not a vector, because it is the dot product between vectors $\vec c$ and $\vec d$. And when using the $diag(a^T b)$ expression I wanted to say: the main diagonal of the matrix $a^T b$, not the trace of it. Does it still make sense? Thanks